# Is there a way to have 2 collections of selected rows in Kendo Grid for Angular

Tags: angular, kendo-grid

I am trying to create a grid where users can select duplicate data to merge. I was planning on having 2 checkbox columns. One checkbox will signify the record id to keep, the other will keep tracking of the records ids to change. My plan was to use the normal selected rows functionality and create another collection of selected rows for the "child" records. I'm stuck on getting the row data out of the ChildClick call. Can someone tell me what I'm missing?

Here is the kendo grid markup.

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12"> </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
      <div class="grid-container grid-container--scrollable">
        <kendo-grid #grid="kendoGrid" [kendoGridBinding]="gridView" [scrollable]="'none'" [pageSize]="pageSize"
          [skip]="skip" [pageable]="true" filterable="menu" (pageChange)="onPageChange($event)"
          [selectable]="{ enabled: true, checkboxOnly: true, mode: multiple }" [selectedKeys]="selectedRows"
          [kendoGridSelectBy]="selectedRowsHandler">

          <ng-template kendoGridToolbarTemplate>

          </ng-template>
          <kendo-grid-checkbox-column width="40">
            <ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate let-idx="rowIndex">
              <label for="row-{{ idx }}">
                <input [kendoGridSelectionCheckbox]="idx" type="checkbox" id="parentRow-{{ idx }}" />
              </label>
            </ng-template>
          </kendo-grid-checkbox-column><kendo-grid-column field="" title="" width="40">
            <ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate let-dataItem let-idx="rowIndex">
              <input type="checkbox" id="childRow{{ idx }}" onclick="ChildSelect($event)" />
            </ng-template>
          </kendo-grid-column>
          <kendo-grid-column field="firstName" title="First Name"></kendo-grid-column>
          <kendo-grid-column field="lastName" title="Last Name"></kendo-grid-column>

          <kendo-grid-column field="companyName" title="Company Name"></kendo-grid-column>

          <kendo-grid-column field="communicationMethods" title="Communication"> </kendo-grid-column>
          <kendo-grid-column field="city" title="City"></kendo-grid-column>
          <kendo-grid-column field="state" title="State"></kendo-grid-column>

          <kendo-grid-column field="activityCount" title="Activity"></kendo-grid-column>
          <kendo-grid-column field="subscriptionCount" title="Subscriptions"></kendo-grid-column>
        </kendo-grid>
      </div>
      <div>&nbsp;</div>
      <div>
        <button kendoButton (click)="onClick()" (focus)="onFocus()" (blur)="onBlur()">
          Merge
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the typescript.

```ts
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ContactModel } from '../../models/contact.model';
import { ContactService } from '../../services/contact.service';
import { CoreModule } from '../../../core/core.module';
import { RowArgs } from '@progress/kendo-angular-grid';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-all-contacts',
  templateUrl: './all-contacts.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./all-contacts.component.scss']
})
export class AllContactsComponent implements OnInit {
  public pageSize: number = 25;
  public skip: number = 0;
  public filterText: string;

  public gridData: any[];
  public gridView: any[];

  public loading: boolean = false;

  public selectedRows: ContactModel[] = [];

  constructor(
    private contactService: ContactService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.loading = true;
    this.contactService.getAll().subscribe(contacts => {
      this.gridData = contacts;
      this.gridView = contacts;
      this.loading = false;
    });
  }

  // Grid pagination
  public onPageChange(state: any): void {
    this.skip = state.skip;
    this.pageSize = state.take;
  }

  selectedRowsHandler(context: RowArgs): any {
    return context.dataItem;
  }

  private rowsSelected: number[] = [];
  private childrenSelected: number[] = [];

  private rowsSelectedKeys(context: RowArgs): number {
    return context.dataItem.id;
  }

  private selectAllRows(e): void {
    if (e.target.checked) {
      this.rowsSelected = this.gridData.map(o => o.id);
    } else {
      this.rowsSelected = [];
    }
  }

  private ChildSelect(e): void {
    console.log(this.gridView[e.index]);
  }

}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a solution.

html

```
<ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate let-dataItem let-idx="rowIndex">
              <input type="checkbox" id="childRow{{ idx }}" (change)="childClick($event, idx)" name="childRow{{ idx }}" value="{{ dataItem.id }}" />
            </ng-template>
```

Typescript

```
 public childClick(e, idx) {
    console.log(e.target.value);
    console.log(e.target.checked);

    if (e.target.checked) {
      this.selectedChildren.push(e.target.value);
    }
  }
```